# button.form() is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

getting error at that  button.up('form').getForm().reset(); is undefined....

functions of Submit - is send user details to server
cancel button - it sgould reset form.

// this is code of controller for login form..which consist of two event s for submit button & for cancel

```
Ext.define('Packt.controller.Login',
    { 

        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',



         views: [
                    'Login' 

                ],


        init: function(application) 
        { 
            this.control({


                "button#submit": { 
                                        click: this.onButtonClickSubmit 
                                 },

                "button#cancel": { 
                                        click: this.onButtonClickCancel 
                                 }
                        });


        },


        // implementation of action to be executed when events happnes


        onButtonClickSubmit: function(button, e, options)
        {
            get login form referance

            var formPanel = button.up('form'),
            login = button.up('login'),
            user = formPanel.down('textfield[name=user]').getValue(),
            pass = formPanel.down('textfield[name=password]').getValue(),

            if (formPanel.getForm().isValid())
            {
                 encryptting password
                    pass = Packt.util.MD5.encode(pass);

                 sending user details to server

                Ext.Ajax.request({
                                    url: 'php/login.php',
                                    params: {
                                                user: user,
                                                password: pass
                                            }
                                });
            }  


        }, 

        onButtonClickCancel: function(button, e, options)
        {
            button.up('form').getForm().reset();
        } 

});
```

---

code of view for form :

```
Ext.define('Packt.view.Login', { 

        extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

        alias: 'widget.login', 

        autoShow: true, 

        height: 170, 

        width: 360, 

layout: {
        type: 'fit' 
        },

        iconCls: '.key', 
        title: 'Login',
        closeAction: 'hide', 
        closable: false ,


items: [
         {
             type: 'form', 
             frame: false, 
             bodyPadding: 15,

defaults: { 
            xtype: 'textfield', 
            anchor: '100%', 
            labelWidth: 60 ,
            allowBlank: false, 
            vtype: 'alphanum', 
            minLength: 3, 
            msgTarget: 'side'
          },

items: [
         {
             name: 'user',
             fieldLabel: 'user',
             maxLength :25              
         },
         {
             inputType: 'password', 
             name: 'password',
             fieldLabel: 'Password',
             maxLength :15,
             enableKeyEvents: true,
             id: 'password'
         }
       ]
         }
         ],


    dockedItems: [
                  {
                      xtype: 'toolbar',
                      dock: 'bottom',

              items: [
                      {
                          xtype: 'tbfill'
                      },
                      {
                          xtype: 'button', 
                          itemId: 'cancel',
                          iconCls: 'cancel',
                          text: 'Cancel'
                      },
                      {
                          xtype: 'button',
                          itemId: 'submit',
                          formBind: true, 
                          iconCls: 'key-go',
                          text: 'Submit'
                      }
                     ]
                  }
                ] 
});
```

---

this is code of app.js that is main

```
Ext.application({

// namespace fr project

name: 'Packt',

/*requires: [
            'Packt.view.Login'
          ],
   views: [
            'Login'
          ],
          */

controllers: [
                'Login'
             ],

     init: function() 
     {
          splashscreen = Ext.getBody().mask('Loading application','splashscreen');
            splashscreen.addCls('splashscreen');

            Ext.DomHelper.insertFirst(Ext.query('.x-mask-msg')[0], {cls: 'x-splash-icon' }); 



            splashscreen.next().fadeOut({
                duration: 1000,
                remove:true,
                listeners: {
                            afteranimate: function(el, startTime, eOpts )
                                { 
                                    Ext.widget('login');
                            }
                            }
           }); 


    }


});
```

Comment: First of all, you have two click events defined for the submit button, and none for the cancel button. Second, it sounds like it can't find the form, so could you please show us the code where the form and buttons in question are created?

Comment: hallo sir , i pasted correct code

Comment: Does the submit button work? Also, is the exact error message you are getting `button.form() is undefined`?

Comment: its working now..........:)

Comment: So what was the issue?

Comment: issue was just of for , i had written 'type' instead of xtype........ :)